# How do i login when i cant access wp-login.php?

Tags: plugins, login

i have a self hosted wordpress install on a server in a virtbox at home.
i was trying out plugins from the wordpress.org site, and after enabling some securtiy plugins, i found i couldnt access the wp-login.php page anymore.
i get a function of one of the plugins telling me the site is forbidden and doesnt exist.
the problem is, i am not exactly sure which plugin did this.
i dont have a login link on the front end of the page also.
the plugins i have installed are bulletproof security, lockdown wp-admin, ultimate security checker, and wp security scan.
the install is on an ubuntu server with no GUI, host is mac osx, but i can access it from the network.
if i just delete the plugins from the wordpress directory, will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have shell access to the server (which is sounds like you do), rename the `wp-content/plugins` directory to something else (I often just stick an `x` in front) and see if you can get into your site. Then create a new plugins directory and move the plugins one at a time from `xplugins/` to `plugins/`. You'll soon know who the culprit is.

Comment: worked great, i was worried about the settings staying the same which is why i didnt delete. I am glad that i didnt